# How I enable Guide Lines in Visual Studio Code with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

How I enable Guide Lines in Visual Studio Code with Flutter?

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `settings.json`:

`File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"`

and add:

```
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true,
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": true,
```

Comment: they have to be in the Settings GUI too

Comment: I think this Flutter setting might only be in ```settings.json```, if you can find it then update my answer.

Comment: I don't use Dart, but every configured setting is available in the GUI

Answer (score 1):

**If someone wants to achieve this with GUI way:**

- GoTo VS code setting==> search: `PreviewUI` ==> check `Dart:Preview flutter Ui Guides`

[image]